# how to check if a name exist multiple times in an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i need to check if there is the name john more than 3 times in the names key within the following array that contains 4 different sub arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 4.2
            [name] => john
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
            [name] => john
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [total] => 3
            [name] => adam
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1.5
            [name] => john
        )

)
```

i was using mysql first but i prefer to use php instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 $counts = array_count_values(array_column($array,"name"));
```

Then to check if there's 3 people called "john" :

```
 if (isset($counts["john"]) && $counts["john"] >= 3) {
      //Do stuff
 } else {
      //Do different stuff
  }
```

To find check all peole not called "john" you can either change the above to as @Andreas suggests:

```
  if (isset($counts["john"]) && (count($array) - $counts["john"]) > 3) {
     //Do stuff
 } else {
      //Do different stuff
  }
```

Alternatively do:

```
 $notJohn = count(array_filter($array, function ($element) {
      return $element["name" != "john";
 }));
 if ($notJohn >= 3) ...
```

Comment: that worked perfectly but i asked the question in reverse i want to check how many people are not called john in that array

Comment: Then count array and subtract John

Comment: its an array of 10 elements and the number of johns should not exceed 3, should i do it `<=7`

Comment: I can't see how the question was count "non-john" if John>3. I only see count John. Maybe you need to edit your question to make it more clear. @mirvatJ

Comment: Updated with  @Andreas suggested

Answer (score 0):

Here, **$namesArray** in an array with **repeated value** in it.Target is to count how many time exist each value in array.

> $namesArray =
>   array("John","Mark","John","Dan","Hasib","Milon","Samad","Milon","John");

```
$newArray = array();
    foreach($namesArray as $name){
        if(isset($newArray[$name])){
           $newArray[$name]++;
        }else{
           $newArray[$name] = 1;
        }
    }
```

**According to code here is output :**

```
Array(
  [John] => 3
  [Mark] => 1
  [Dan] => 1
  [Hasib] => 1
  [Milon] => 2
  [Samad] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A function like this will do the work
I have roughly written it in mobile.

```
  $occurence = 0;
  function a() {
  for($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < 2; $y++) {
      if (array[$x][$y] === "John") {
        $occurence++;
      }
    }
  }
  if($occurence > 3) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
    }
 }
```